# I there a way to find by example in QueryDSL?

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

Is it possible to make a QueryDSL predicate using an example entity? For example:

```
Customer customerExample = new Customer();
customerExample.setName("John");
customerExample.setCountry("EUA");
QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
Customer bob = queryFactory.selectFrom(customer)
  .where(customer.example(customerExample )) // matches customers with name like "John" and country like "EUA"
  .fetch();
```

If not, is there any alternative other than using SpringJPA?

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like

```
List<Tuple> searchResults = queryFactory.selectFrom(customer)
      .where(customer.name.eq(customerExample.getName()), customer.country.eq(customerExample.getCountry())
      .fetch();
```

Also, it will return `List<Tuple>` instead of 'Customer'. So you would have to map the results to 'Customer' afterwards.

Comment: Implementing all the query by hand is what I am tring to avoid. In your example, you would have to validate nulls also.